# Use scrollToItemAtIndexPath in UICollectionView with paging

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have an uicollectionview with paging enabled. One cell per page which is full screen basically. The thing is that when I want to use scrollToItemAtIndexPath and move one cell forward/backward along with animation it will do a swipe but it will go back instantly to the cell/page where I called scrollToItemAtIndexPath. There is really nothing special besides stuff I've described. When I omit animation it's working.

For faster debugging I've setup test project on github - [ScrollToItem](https://github.com/strejdashek/ScrollToItem)

EDIT: This might be a bug. Bugreport (18864560) submitted. If someone can provide me a workaround or even solve this issue it will be still appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally instead of None?

Comment: I tried it with UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally, and that didn't work any better. I did notice that if you keep clicking, it sometimes does go forward normally. This looks like a bug to me. I don't see anything wrong in your code.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't spot anything wrong with it, in this cases I always sit and write everything in code. Its much easier to deal with this types of errors. May I upload the code version of this later to git?

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes it does that swipe ok but it's like 20% of cases. Positioncenteredhorizontally did not help me. You can do anything you want with that repo but rewriting into code does not help since I need to implement it in some project which is based on storyboards.